# When an observer and an object in an enclosed area fall under gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, equilibrium

An observer and an object are in a closed container.(the object is tied to a string.)(the container is something like an elevator;not precisely an elevator). First the container is on earth and then it is raised high up. Then the whole thing is released under gravity. During the fall the object is cut from the string that it was tied to..please note that the observer and the object are both in the same container.

Then they have given some statements asking us to state whether they are true or not and why..
The first statement was," the object has no resultant force relative to the observer."
The second statement was," the object is under equilibrium relative to the observer"
The third statement was that the behaviour of the object can be explained through Newton's first law relative to the observer..
Also we have to assume that there is no air resistance, friction or such. (No information was given regarding them)

well this is not a homework given  but this is a question that was given in a question paper for an exam. I first answered it myself but got it wrong.since I am doing the review myself but find it impossible to answer this I referred for help.in addition I am a student who is not learning in English medium and English  is the second language for me.  So there Might be mistakes in English terms and I highly apologize for that and also if convenient please help me through this

Comment: What do you mean by "the observer see that the object is still relative to himself"? I don't understand this sentence. Could you please, clarify it? Thank you. In fact, I need clarification for all three points.

Comment: Sir, I tried posting an image related to this but failed...first of all sir thanks for giving time and I am learning in another language  so there might be mistakes in my English terms ..I apologise..sir, the question was, there is a man and an object: the object is tied to a string ,in a closed container.The container is first on earth and then it is taken high up and released under gravity. During the fall the object is cut from the string. It is asked how the observer, then observe the motion of the object relative to him..it is given as statement and we are to find out whether they are tru

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you mean that you have an enclosed volume, like an elevator, which is freely falling under the influence of gravity, with no air resistance or other forms of friction?

Comment: The first statement was ,that the observer relative to himself sees the object has no resultant force. The second statement was that the observer observes( relative to himself) that the object is under equilibrium .the third statement was that the observer relative to himself  can explain this behaviour of the object through Newton's first law..

Comment: So sorry if convenient could you please explain me whether the statements are true or false and why

Comment: @Stratiev..sir I have given further details..if convenient please explain..and also thank you very much for giving time

Comment: Please note that both the observer and the object are in the same container

Comment: @PM 2Ring...yea I know..I highly apologise for the inconvenience..and yes we gotta assume as you have mentioned here on your comment.and also in other comments I did write what exactly the question is.. I'm quite new to this app..so please excuse me for the mistakes

Comment: You don't need to apologise. But you do need to [edit] your question to make it more clear. Don't bury that information down here in the comments.

Comment: This may help [Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178417/37364)