# How does mass warp space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime

Einstein gave us the mechanism to explain how gravity works. (Namely that mass curves (or warps) space-time.) Do we have any theories for the "mechanism" as to how masses warp space? Is it related to the Higgs field?

Comment: This may help. [Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178417/37364)

Comment: *Is it related to the Higgs field?* No. Peter Higgs wasn’t born when Einstein proposed General Relativity.

Comment: In my opinion, Einstein’s field equations and the geodesic equation are a sufficient and satisfying gravitational “mechanism” for most physicists. They’re not too conceptually different from Maxwell’s equations and the Lorentz force law, which are sufficient and satisfying for electromagnetism.