# Does the material of the screen affect the interference pattern of the electrons in the double-slit experiment?

Tags: material-science, interference, double-slit-experiment

The question comes from thinking about the way how the screen material affects the interference pattern. Let's say that half of the screen was from one material and the other half from different material. Would interference patter be affected by this?

Another question is whether the interference patter would be affected if both halves of the screen were made of the same material but the surface structure of one half would be different (e.g. more smooth) from the other half.

Answer (score 2):

In a double-slit experiment, the “screen” is simply shorthand for a detector that determines the location of electrons (or photons or whatever is being used in the experiment) at a given distance from the slits. It may signal the arrival of an electron in different ways (red flashes or blue flashes, for example) and it may work more or less efficiently, but the nature of the detector has no effect on the interference pattern itself, which is a theoretical construct.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know some particular experiments which tested different materials (or generally different surface properties) for detectors and their effects on the probability of the quantum wave collapsing in that particular detector?

Comment: Detection equals collapse.  The two are not separable.

Comment: @TKN detection is easy for photons, any screen that shows light . see this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/634523/how-does-the-energy-mass-equivalence-not-contradict-conservation-of-energy/634537#634537 . for one photon at a time see this  https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/