# How gravity would affect light "perceived" speed?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light

Here is the experience:

A photon P travels from X to Y through tube drilled inside the earth from the North Pole to the South Pole.
A photon Q travels from A to B, which is the exact same segment translated outside the gravity pull of the earth.

Would the photon P take more time to reach its destination than the photon Q? Said otherwise, does the curvature of space generated by the earth's gravity makes the distance longer?

[image]

Comment: This may help - [Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178417/37364)

Comment: this may interest you https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/general_relativity/#Free  . Also note that your AB photon will not go in a straight line, as in the tunnel, because of the asymmetry of the field and GR there will be gravitational lensing.